# Tensorflow dimensions /placeholders

Tags: tensorflow

I want to run a neural network in tensorflow. I am trying to do email classification, so my training data is an array of count vectorized documents.

Im trying to understand the dimensions for how I should input data into tensorflow. I am creating placeholders like this:

X = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, #features]

Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, #labels])

then later, I have to transform the actual y_train to have dimensionality (1, #observations) since I get some dimensionality errors when I run the code.

Should the placeholders and the variables have the same dimensionality? What is the correspondence? I am getting out of memory errors, so am concerned that I have something wrong with the input dimensions.

Comment: You may need to transform y_train to have dimension (#observation, #labels) by one-hot encoding. The placeholders and actual data need to have the same dimension, except the dimension defined by `None` (which only need to be consistent among the actual input). BTW this question should be better asked in StackOverflow or StackExchange:DataScience.

Answer (score 1):

A little unsure as to what your "#" symbols refer. This if often used to mean "number" in which case what you have written would be incorrect. To be clear you want to define your placeholders for X and Y as

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, input_dimensions])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, 1])
```

Here the `None` values accommodate the number of samples in the training data you pass in; if you feed in 10 emails, `None` will be 10. The `input_dimensions` means "how long is the vector that represents a single training example". In the case of a grey-scale image this would be equal to the number of pixels, in the case of your e-mail inputs this should be the length of the longest vectorized email.

All of your email inputs will need to be input at the same length, and a common practice for all those shorter than the longest email is to pad the vectors up to the max length with zeros.

When comparing `Y` to the training labels (`y_train`) they should both be tensors of the same shape. So as `Y` has shape (number_of_emails, 1), so should `y_train`.  You can convert from `(1, number_of_emails)` to `(number_of_emails, 1)` using

```
y_train = tf.reshape(y_train, [-1,1])
```

Finally the out of memory errors are unlikely to be to do with any dimension miss-match, but more likely you are feeding too many emails into the network at once. Each time you feed in some emails as `X` they must be held in memory. If there are many emails, feeding them all in at once will exhaust the memory resources (particularly if training on a GPU). For this reason it is common practice to batch your inputs into smaller groups fed in sequentially. Tensorflow provides a guide to [importing data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets), as well as specific help on [batching](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#simple_batching).